# css alignment issue with overflow and inlined objects with overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a div display:inline-block with overflow:hidden.  My problem is that the overflow:hidden pushes down adjacent inline-block elements.

Demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/vNDmX/

Can anyone explain why this happens, and how do I fix it?

**Update:** This is a firefox specific issue.  float:left works somewhat, but it still mucks with the spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/vNDmX/3/.

Comment: The demonstration you posted does not outline the problem.

Comment: Yes, it appears that it is a Firefox-specific issue.  Damn.

Comment: float:left instead of inline:block works fine.

Comment: Why not change inline-block to `display:block; float:left;`?

Comment: float:left does and doesn't work.  see: http://jsfiddle.net/vNDmX/3/.  It still mucks with the spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Firefox-specific bug (here's [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052619/vertical-alignment-problem-with-overflow-hidden-inline-block-and-vertical) I found when investigating this). The fix seems to be setting `vertical-align: top`.

Here's an example of the fix, along with some borders added to show elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/vNDmX/5/

```
button {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  If I could give you +10, I would!  Thanks m8!

Comment: @Blazes For various other layout issues, when using `display: inline-block;`, you should almost always use `vertical-align: top;`.

Comment: This is occurring in Chrome too.

Answer (score 1):

Try with float:

**HTML5**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button id="button1">Button1</button>
        <button id="button2">Button2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrapper = '<div style="display:block;float:left;" />';
    $('#button1').wrap(wrapper);
});
```

Comment: changed, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if setting the overflow on the `div` is causing it to lose track of where its baseline is. Its baseline should be the baseline of the `button`, but instead it's the bottom of the `button`. This means that the second `button` tries to align its baseline to the wrong place. One way to work around this is to use `vertical-align: bottom;` on the `div`.